# Download file on existing SSH session

Tags: ssh, download, upload

Is there any way to download a file on an existing SSH session?

I know we can use scp but how come there is no command to download / upload a file **while** you are on a ssh session?

e.g

```
server(myuser) > download remote-file-location local-file-location
```

Comment: scp can push as well as pull (assuming the other host has ssh also) so you can just scp the file in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

If your SSH client supports zmodem (e.g. Kitty), you can use `sz filename`.

Otherwise you can play with `uuencode`, `cat`, SSH logging and `uudecode`.

Comment: My ssh client or my ssh server machine? I'm using the built in open-ssh client @ linux

Comment: @Fisher: Client. As far as I know, the Linux client doesn't support zmodem.